# Unable to start the celery workers (Flask Application)

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying out celery with Python Flask.

### celery_example.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from flask import Flask
from flask_celery import make_celery

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqp://rsrc:rsrc@localhost:5672/localhost',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='db+postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/rsrc_celery'
)

celery = make_celery(flask_app)

@flask_app.route('/process/<name>')
def process(name):
    reverse.delay(name)
    return "Async !"


@celery.task(name="celery_example.reverse")
def reverse(nm):
    return nm[::-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

### flask_celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

FLask server is up and running fine, I'm able to call the route that is defined.
But I'm unable to start the Celery worker (**celery worker -A celery_example.celery --loglevel=info**)
This is the error I get always.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 290, in execute_from_commandline
    self.on_error(UNABLE_TO_LOAD_APP_MODULE_NOT_FOUND.format(e.name))
AttributeError: 'exceptions.ImportError' object has no attribute 'name'
```

### My directory structure is

```
--Flask_Celery
   -- celery_example.py
   -- flask_celery.py
   -- __init__.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so what the problem was the environment.

I was creating the environment by "virtualenv env" which was creating the environment with python, whereas I needed the python3 environment.

So, I created virtual environment using "python3 -m venv env" and then loaded all the dependencies which resolved the error.